# Javascript: convert string with full month to date object

Tags: javascript, string, date

I have a string variable `"PublishDate"` and then when I check the value using `"PublishDate.value"` it returns a string like

`"October 04, 2016 9:28 AM"`

I need to convert it to a date object that is formatted like `"10/04/2016"`

I am not sure how this is done in javascript:

```
var d = new Date("October 04, 2016 9:28 AM");
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hours = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();   //10/04/2016
console.log(month+1+'/'+date+'/'+year);
```

Comment: Either you have a date object, or you have the string `"10/04/2016"`, you can't have both at the same time *(but you could have both in different variables)*

Comment: what research have you done and what have you tried? Using keywords from in this question in a search engine will produce many many results

Comment: Just parse the string and create the date object yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert that String date into a Date object using the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var d = new Date(PublishDate.value);
```

---

**EDIT:** Always consider the case that your format may not be supported by the browser. In the case of Firefox, the MDN states that it will support [certain date formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters):

> The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method
>   (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

[IE's MSDN Javascript reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx#Anchor_2) also says:

> It first tries to parse a date string by using the [ISO Date Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx#ISO). If
>   the date string is not in ISO format, JavaScript tries to parse the
>   date by using other [Other Date Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx#OtherDateFormats).

Also, consider that the MDN itself discourages parsing String dates using the constructor or `Date.parse()`, even though it works for your specific case:

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
>   Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies.

If you need to support other varieties of date formats or a variety of browsers, you can also consider [Momtent.js](http://momentjs.com/) javascript library or do your own parsing with RegEx, like in @RobG's and @adeneo's answers.

---

Then, you need to extract the parts you want (month, day, year) and concatenate them in a string with the slash as a separator, like in @user3254198's answer or @Steeve Pitis's answer:

```
d.getDate() + '/' 
    + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' 
    +  d.getFullYear()
```

Remember that the `PublishDate.value.getMonth()` method returns a zero-based month numerical representation of the month, so if you want a 1-12 value, add a `+1` to it.

Feel free to ask any further! Good luck.

Comment: Really, your browser outputs that format when for date objects? Mine would output UTC dates, as in `2016-10-04T09:28:00.000Z` etc ?

Comment: Yes! minus the GMT part: `console.log(new Date().toString());` prints `Tue Oct 04 2016 10:36:13 GMT-0600` in my browser.

Comment: That's still not even close to `October 04, 2016 9:28 AM`

Comment: Sorry, I saw it similar at first look, but you are right it is different. I'll update my answer.

Comment: "*First, convert that String date into a Date object using the Date constructor:*" is not a good idea. Parsing of the OP date format is entirely implementation dependent and may return the correct date, the wrong date or an invalid date.

Comment: Thanks RobG, you are right about discouraing the use of Date constructor and Date.parse() for parsing dates. I expanded my answer to add warnings and another alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of months to get the numerical value, and then just parse it however you'd like

```js
var months = [
 "January",
 "February",
 "March",
 "April",
  "May",
  "June",
 "July",
  "August",
  "September",
 "October",
 "November",
 "December"
];

function pad(n) { return n<10?'0'+n:n }

var PublishDate = {
 value : "October 04, 2016 9:28 AM"
}

var parts = PublishDate.value.split(/[\s\,\:]+/);
var year  = +parts[2];
var month = months.indexOf(parts[0]);
var day   = +parts[1];

var date  = new Date(year, month, day);                  // date object
var str   = pad(month+1) + '/' + pad(day) + '/' +  year; // the string "10/04/2016"

console.log(date);
console.log(str);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top : 0}
```

Comment: wow there is actually a much easier way ^^ `new Date("October 04, 2016 9:28 AM")` works fine ^^

Comment: @SteevePitis - good for you, but it's not a valid ISO 8601 date, so wether or not the engine is able to parse it, would be implementation dependant, and not guaranteed at all.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Example PublishDate result
var PublishDate = {
  value: 'October 04, 2016 9:28 AM'
};

// convert "date string" into "date object"
var date = new Date(PublishDate.value);

// build required "date string"
var dateShort = (date.getMonth() +1) + '/'
  + date.getDate() + '/'
  + date.getFullYear();

// console log to show result
console.log(dateShort);
```

Comment: Need to add a `+ 1` to the `date.getMonth()` part, since that method returns a zero based month number so it is printing 
10/4/2016 instead of 9/04/2016

Answer (score 1):

Parsing a string like "October 04, 2016 9:28 AM" using the Date constructor is entirely implementation dependent and may result in an incorrect date or invalid date, so either use a parser (there are many good ones available) or write a small function yourself to parse the string.

But if you just want to reformat it, then parsing to a Date isn't required at all, just reformat the string. E.g.

```js
/* Reformat a string like October 04, 2016 9:28 AM to m/d/y format
** @param {string} s - string in format MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm ap
** @returns {string} reformatted date in MM/DD/YYYY format
*/
function reformatDate(s) {
  var months = {jan:'01',feb:'02',mar:'03',apr:'04', may:'05',jun:'06',
                jul:'07',aug:'08',sep:'09',oct:'10',nov:'11',dec:'12'};
  var b = s.match(/\w+/g) || [];
  return months[b[0].toLowerCase().substr(0,3)] + '/' + b[1] + '/' + b[2];
}

console.log(reformatDate('October 04, 2016 9:28 AM'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of question like this on SO ... Try to search a little next time.

```
var date = new Date(PublishDate.value);
console.log((date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Parsing of the OP date format is entirely implementation dependent and may return the correct date, the wrong date or an invalid date. Either write a simple function or use one of the many parsers available.