# Convert date format in vue js with laravel

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using verta library to convert gregorian dates to hijri date in laravel
https://github.com/hekmatinasser/verta

in simple mode (.blade.php files) I'm using code like this:

```
{{ Verta($category->created_at)->format('%d %B %Y') }}
for converting {{created_at}}
```

but in Vue js I can't access to this format an I have

```
{{category.created_at}}
```

how can I convert the vue js dates with this method?

Comment: if you want to reuse what you are doing in laravel you will need to parse the dates before returning them to the frontend. you can use mutations (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators) to do this automatically when reading database entries

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708110/convert-date-format-in-javascript-using-vuejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mutator on your model to parse the date before returning it.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Verta($value)->format('%d %B %Y');
}
```

This should be defined on your Category Model

```
{{category.created_at}}
```

Will then contain the already parsed date

Comment: Yes the best way is creating one attribute.. don't forget add it to the append array

Comment: as created_at is an actual database field you don't need to append it (in this specific case / question)

Answer (score 7):

Simply, You can do it by follow three steps by moment.js.

Step 1:

```
npm install moment --save
```

Step 2:

```
import moment from "moment";
```

Step 3:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            moment: moment
        }
    } }
```

Done.

Now do in below

```
 {{ moment(category.created_at).format("DD-MM-YYYY") }}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @dhan for your compliment.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel Side

```
1)
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d-m-Y');
}

2)protected $casts = [
    'birthday'  => 'date:Y-m-d'
];
```

In Vue .js side make filters

```
npm install moment

In  resources/js/app.js

import moment from 'moment';

Vue.filter('formatDate', function(value) {
    if (value) {
        return moment(String(value)).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    }
});
```

in Vue component side

```
{{ category.created_at | formatDate }}
```

Comment: Vue 3 has deprecated filters - https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vue-moment`.

```
npm install vue-moment
```

...and require the plugin like so:

```
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
```

Then, in your application you can do something like this:

```
{{ someDate | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }}
```

**Deprecated in Vue 3**

Comment: Vue 3 has deprecated filters - https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html