# Format date with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i want to format this date `<b-button variant="outline-primary">{{getContract.contract_data.start_date}} | {{getContract.contract_data.end_date}}</b-button>` Now it looks like this: [image]

I want it to be seen like this: [image]

how can i do?

I solved it with MomentJS: [Convert date format in Javascript using VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708110/convert-date-format-in-javascript-using-vuejs)

Comment: It seems like you're receiving the date as a string: what about tackling it at the source and ensuring that a unix timestamp (in ms) is being used? Then it is a matter of passing that number to the `Date()` object and using `toLocaleString` to format it any way you like.

Comment: Thanks @Terry how can i do this?

Comment: Ensure that your `contract_data`'s `start_date` and `end_date` are unix timestamps not strings, convert it to a date object, i.e. `new Date(getContract.contract_data.start_date)`, then read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Do you know momentJS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708110/convert-date-format-in-javascript-using-vuejs

Comment: @Fabrizio Whenever answering (or solving) your question, please post an answer so that it can be easily found by other developers that might have the same question

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use dayjs instead, or luxon, momentjs is not getting any further support… and actually authors recommend to migrate to other solutions instead.